# Removing old coordinate and adding a new one into that index - Python

Tags: python-3.x, append, tuples, coordinates

I have a set of random positions with their indices as follows:

```
pos = {0: (65, 0), 1: (143, 96), 2: (2, 45), 3: (128, 19), 4: (91, 34), 5: (105, 127), 6: (80, 29), 7: (148, 134), 8: (53.0, 46.5), 9: (116.0, 33.5), 10: (104.5, 87.5), 11: (62.25, 28.25), 12: (69.25, 74.75), 13: (56.75, 25.75), 14: (90.75, 78.25), 15: (93.75, 21.75), 16: (100.75, 68.25), 17: (88.25, 19.25), 18: (122.25, 71.75), 19: (116.5, 98.75)}
```

After few more mathematical operations, I found that the coordinates of the points  `[8, 17, 20, 9, 11, 21, 10, 19, 14, 22, 16]` have changed accordingly as

```
[(64.933003914056954, 73.512353385691156), (67.609354584781386, 29.084825707397332), (65.055487297822125, 71.479138365156629), (65.634499205445252, 61.867750510493728), (65.551876571641429, 63.239283293792454), (66.366807024791072, 49.711182456213727), (65.485681419116816, 64.338102471328327), (65.308178284791879, 67.284467319880079), (67.031361074876017, 38.679499846625028), (67.286696006705057, 34.440985282832173), (65.062957777139445, 71.355123241241017)].
```

Now I need to remove the old coordinate corresponds to those indices from `pos` and add the new one into it. 
How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
pos = {0: (65, 0), 1: (143, 96), 2: (2, 45), 3: (128, 19), 4: (91, 34), 5: (105, 127), 6: (80, 29), 7: (148, 134), 8: (53.0, 46.5), 9: (116.0, 33.5), 10: (104.5, 87.5), 11: (62.25, 28.25), 12: (69.25, 74.75), 13: (56.75, 25.75), 14: (90.75, 78.25), 15: (93.75, 21.75), 16: (100.75, 68.25), 17: (88.25, 19.25), 18: (122.25, 71.75), 19: (116.5, 98.75)}
points = [8, 17, 20, 9, 11, 21, 10, 19, 14, 22, 16]
val = [(64.933003914056954, 73.512353385691156), (67.609354584781386, 29.084825707397332), (65.055487297822125, 71.479138365156629), (65.634499205445252, 61.867750510493728), (65.551876571641429, 63.239283293792454), (66.366807024791072, 49.711182456213727), (65.485681419116816, 64.338102471328327), (65.308178284791879, 67.284467319880079), (67.031361074876017, 38.679499846625028), (67.286696006705057, 34.440985282832173), (65.062957777139445, 71.355123241241017)]
for i, key in enumerate(points):
    pos[key] = val[i]
```

the pos will look like this:

```
{0: (65, 0),
 1: (143, 96),
 2: (2, 45),
 3: (128, 19),
 4: (91, 34),
 5: (105, 127),
 6: (80, 29),
 7: (148, 134),
 8: (64.93300391405695, 73.51235338569116),
 9: (65.63449920544525, 61.86775051049373),
 10: (65.48568141911682, 64.33810247132833),
 11: (65.55187657164143, 63.239283293792454),
 12: (69.25, 74.75),
 13: (56.75, 25.75),
 14: (67.03136107487602, 38.67949984662503),
 15: (93.75, 21.75),
 16: (65.06295777713945, 71.35512324124102),
 17: (67.60935458478139, 29.084825707397332),
 18: (122.25, 71.75),
 19: (65.30817828479188, 67.28446731988008),
 20: (65.05548729782213, 71.47913836515663),
 21: (66.36680702479107, 49.71118245621373),
 22: (67.28669600670506, 34.44098528283217)}
```